# Convert autodesk .dwg and .dwf files to three.js json format

Tags: json, three.js, autodesk, dwg

I want to render 3D graphics files of autodesk (.dwg and .dwf) using three.js but three.js requires 3D data to be in json format. So, I need to convert these files to three.js readable json format. I tried searching on the internet but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone tell me a good converter for these files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact Autodesk already have a converter & wegbl viewer. Go to http://developer.autodesk.com and get a key for View & Data API. There is a server side REST API that allow you to upload a CAD file and convert to a JSON stream. You can hook to it and get the output. Or, even easier, just use the JavaScript client side API to embed the viewer on your website/app

**Update**

The API was renamed to [Model Derivative](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/) + [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/overview/), the first translates the source file (e.g. `DWG`, `RVT` and many others) to a web-friendly format that can be viewed on the second, which is based on Three.js (and can be customized).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I need 3D model data containing all the vertices and other information to separately render the 3D model in my rendering application.Is it possible to download that JSON stream?

Comment: after you upload the CAD file and translate (using REST APIs), you can use the JavaScript to download the JSON stream. I'm not sure if there is a public sample, but I know some developers are doing it...

Comment: Ok, I will try downloading JSON stream using JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: I found this demo on the internet: http://extract.autodesk.io/ that serves my purpose. I want to use it for my website. Are there any charges for it's commercial usage?

Comment: will have a cost, but so far is not decided yet. If you have a commercial app already, Autodesk team can help on biz side, send your contact to my email (check my first . last name @ autodesk.com)

Comment: Ok, I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @amit did you find a way to convert dwg to json via REST? I looked around a bit and did not find any urls that would enable it. Also nothing from google...

Comment: Does anyone have an example how to do it? We also want to convert dwg-files to JSON but no clear answer can be found on the net

Comment: @ReinVanLeirsberghe please check the sample live at http://extract.autodesk.io/ (or code at https://github.com/cyrillef/workflow-node.js-server-view.and.data.api )

Comment: Murray, take a look at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs

Comment: Oh, of course Autodesk have a converter, but they will never share it in form of application. Only allow to use their service. Autodesk is such Autodesk...